# Error looking up function 'TessBaseAPICreate': libtesseract.so: undefined symbol: TessBaseAPICreate

Tags: java, ocr

I have created a simple swing application which does the ocr of certain form.
The problem is I have a utility class which has a static method

```
public static String readImage(BufferedImage image){
    String str = null;

    //Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();  // JNA Interface Mapping
     Tesseract1 instance = new Tesseract1(); // JNA Direct Mapping

     try {
        System.out.println("Starting OCR process at " + new Date() + "... ");
        str = instance.doOCR(image);            
     } catch (TesseractException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
     }        
     return str;
}
```

Now when I use this method following error occurs

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'TessBaseAPICreate': libtesseract.so: undefined symbol: TessBaseAPICreate
at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:179)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:391)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:371)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1401)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1065)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI1.<clinit>(TessAPI1.java:37)
    at com.discusit.ocr.ocrutil.OCRUtil.readImage(OCRUtil.java:22)
    at com.discusit.form.OCRForm.browseButtonActionPerformed(OCRForm.java:350)
    at com.discusit.form.OCRForm.access$000(OCRForm.java:26)
    at com.discusit.form.OCRForm$1.actionPerformed(OCRForm.java:103)
t javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I have already placed liblept168.dll,
libtesseract.so and libtesseract302.dll in my project root folder.

I am unable to figure out what to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The images I am using are scanned images of some forms. These forms are also some what like this one : http://servingtogetherproject.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dd214-sample-form-lg.jpg what can i do to recognize the letters properly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [make and install Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling) first to have the `.so` files in the appropriate locations. If you have problem with the soft link, take a look at [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/tesseract-ocr/tess4j/tesseract-ocr/bAA390P-bLE/29G7TncgSjoJ) at Tesseract Forum.

Comment: "This post" doesn't exist anymore. That's why it's recommended not to just paste links to off site.